# Is there a sign for 'per decem'?

Tags: notation, percentages

There are signs for per cent (%), per mille (‰), per myriad (‱) et cetera, but is there a sign representing one part per ten, or 'per decem'?

If so, how does it look like? If not, why not?

Comment: For what its worth, you can easily get away with only using percent signs and never use any of the others your whole life.  I don't see the benefit a perdecem sign would bring.  It would just make one more symbol to remember and have a chance of mistaking for something else if reading quickly.  I, for one, am glad to not know of any such symbol.

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q='per+decem') only seems to show actual Latin (*per decem annos*: for ten years). If nobody uses it the way you are thinking and $^0\!/$ looks weird, then perhaps you have an answer.  There are units which are tenths, such as *decibels* (dB) and in some countries *deciliters* (dl), so perhaps the symbol is "d-".

Comment: To give you a perspective – I've created a plot where I had to scale a variable to parts per ten for readibility and I wanted to showcase this unit in the legend like this – Variable name (%) – without having to write it out. 

@ JMoravitz Following your logic one would also not need percent, because one could use permille.

@Henry I was thinking about ⁰⁄  too, that would only be logical. And it seems one can easily create it out of the unicode symbols U+2070 and U+2044

Comment: I would write "/10" after the number and call it a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 'ppt' is already used for 'parts per trillion', I'd settle for the sign ⁰⁄  that was proposed.